# How to decrypt an encrypted password from MySQL for login?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, encryption, jasypt

I'm saving encrypted password into MySQL and want to decrypt for login.
Using `jasypt` library.

```
private void jSaveButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    String secretKey = "AEr@12#3e234";
    StrongTextEncryptor strongTextEncryptor = new StrongTextEncryptor();
    strongTextEncryptor.setPassword(secretKey);

    String value = jPasswordField.getPassword().toString();
    String pass = strongTextEncryptor.encrypt(value);
    bLManager.save(new Employee(jEmpName.getText(), pass));
    jEncodeTextField1.setText(pass);
}  

private void jLoginButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    String secretKey = "AEr@12#3e234";
    StrongTextEncryptor strongTextEncryptor = new StrongTextEncryptor();
    strongTextEncryptor.setPassword(secretKey);

    String passwd = jPasswordField.getPassword().toString();
    String password = strongTextEncryptor.encrypt(passwd); 

    Employee employee = bLManager.login(jEmpName.getText(), password);// getting NPE
}
```

Is it possible decrypt with `Hibernate` using Criteria?

```
public Employee login(String name, String password) {
    Session session = sf.openSession();
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Employee.class);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("name", name));
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("password", password));
    Employee employee = (Employee) criteria.uniqueResult();
    session.close();
    return employee;
}
```

> `String password = strongTextEncryptor.encrypt(passwd);` I encrypt same string here so  it'd match with encrypted password stored in database.

So how to decode or any way around?

Comment: if some algorithm can decrypt data without user's input then hackers who have access to algorithm can do it as well, right? Then why to encrypt it at all? - just store it in plain-text. What use case do you plan to protect/prevent? database dump leakage? What about your binary artifact(key) leakage?

Comment: @MaximSagaydachny I won't that someone access plain text passwords from database so I used another way to do is MessageDigest.

Comment: I just hope this is for your school exercise. DO NOT STORE USER PASSWORDS (even encrypted). Please read and try to understand [how-to-store-your-users-passwords-safely](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2013/11/20/serious-security-how-to-store-your-users-passwords-safely/) .

Comment: @gusto2 I have this in production use. Thanks I'll check it out.

Comment: With MySQL maybe you could at least use `select ... where password=PASSWORD($1)` , where the password hashing is in responsibility of the database. And using SSL to communicate with the DB could ensure confidentiality. Not perfect , but much better than having an encryption key hardcoded in the code.

Comment: Thank for your time. I've read the link you have provided so I've decided to use salt, PBKDF2, bcrypt or scrypt, HMAC-SHA-256 hash.

Comment: I've referred this example [Advanced password security using PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1 algorithm](https://howtodoinjava.com/security/how-to-generate-secure-password-hash-md5-sha-pbkdf2-bcrypt-examples/#PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1) so let me know if it would be great practice and study to do.

Comment: I'd see more concerns to address (e. g. imagine a user able to decompile the code, seems he would gain access to the database connection or could skip the authentication). But that's a different story. You asked about the authentication and yes, salted hash (pbkdf2, bcrypt, scrypt, argon2) is currently the best we have

Comment: @gusto2 So what about embedded database and let me know if it is possible someone able to decompile the code after deploying native packaging.  Thanks

Comment: In an embedded db there should be only single user's data, so the embedded db has its use (you mentioned mysql before). And everything that resides on client's side can be decompiled, you can just make it more difficult (mostly is not worth the effort)